# iPad exits fullscreen mode on scrolling down

Tags: javascript, ipad, webkitrequestfullscreen

I have a design where a div covers the whole viewport (a teleprompter app). Although I have managed iPads to enter fullscreen mode using the fullscreen api, as soon as I scroll DOWNWARDs the content of the div (overflow-y: scroll), the iPad moves the overlay itself (so the elements below it show) and – if you scroll further – exits the fullscreen mode.

Scrolling UP, on the other hand, has no negative effect, the behavior is as expected and the content of the div is scrolled. It also has no effect if I scroll downwards with an angle, so not absolutely on the y-axis but more like 45 degrees downward stroke.

Is this a bug in the API?

Comment: Had the same issue before. Overscrolling can be fixed only on the native side..

Comment: @Raphael: So you agree, it is an error in the API? So preventing the scrolling by a listener would not change this, right?

Comment: Hard to say whats the reason but this was the case for us at least...

Comment: Thanks. I will do some more testing, but it feels like an error in the API. Will need to check with Android devices, too. If they handle it properly, then it will be most definitely be an Apple thing.

Comment: We had same problem with Windows. Only Android behaved properly. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for that. When you say "we HAD the same problems": Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Yes, my friend fixed it on the native side but not certain what he did